# Return out of method instead of returning anything or null

Tags: c#, methods

```
public static string DecryptString(string EncryptedString)
{
    try 
    {
        ....... 
        ....
    }
    catch
    {
        return something else if decryption fails instead of null or empty string; 
    }
}
```

I am trying to return error if the decryption fails not the string.

Comment: Do not catch the exception unless you want to do something useful like logging, it will automatically pass exception to calling method

Comment: add "throw"  statement before return it.

Comment: Basically i wanted an better solution to my problem, so i asked this question i have a code which does the decryption than this string is again used by some method  to separate date time from it , what i was trying to achieve is to call some method if it fails and redirect my user  to some other page.

Comment: @Down Voters why you people don't comment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities: remove try-catch/throw useful exception and handle exception outside of the method

```
public static string DecryptString(string EncryptedString)
{
    try 
    {
        /* your logic here */
        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new DecryptStringFailedException(e);
    }
}
```

or return a boolean flag which indicates the result of the operation:

```
public static bool DecryptString(string EncryptedString, out string result)
{
    try 
    {
        /* your logic here */
        result = ...;
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i need to catch the type of exception and than handle it like so DecryptStringFailedException.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the logic of `int.TryParse`. It returns `bool` showing whether conversion was successful or not, and `out` the value if conversion was successful.

Map the scenario for you.

```
public static bool DecryptString(string EncryptedString, out string Output)
{
    try 
    {
        Output = //decrypted value
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        Output = String.Empty;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not the logic of `int.Parse` which throws an Exception?

Comment: Cause OP didn't ask for it

Comment: @DownVoter Would you like to comment whats the issue you found in the answer?